# Ajuda com regex em Java - sequencia de números separados por vírgula

Tags: java, regex

Estou quebrando a cabeça para montar uma expressão regular que valide a String:

```
/aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,2,3
```

`String reg = "/aluno/[0-9]+/[^0-9]+/......."`

Não estou conseguindo validar o **último** campo (a sequencia de números) que:

- Pode ser de infinitos números separados por vírgula.
- Não pode terminar em nada que não seja um número.

Ou seja, os exemplos `"1,2,3,"`, `"1,2,3a"` ou `"1,2,3,a"` não podem ser aceitos. Apenas sequências válidas, como `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`...

Alguém disposto a ajudar??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar este regex:

```
(\\/[\\d,]+\\d)$
```

Explicação:

```
\\/[\\d,] -> qualquer número precedido por vírgula até a barra
+         -> quantificador: une duas ou mais ocorrências
\\d$      -> termina com um número
(...)     -> salva a ocorrência em um grupo
```

Exemplos:

```
aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,2,33,3,4 // retorna OK!
aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,2,33,3,4a // retorna Inválido! por causa do "a" no final
aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,2,33,3,a // retorna Inválido! por causa do "a" no final
aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,2,33a,3 // retorna Inválido! por causa do "a" no meio
```

[**Teste no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/xnLYyP)

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Use o *pattern* `/aluno/\\d+?/\\D+?/(\\d+?,)*?\\d+`.

- `(\\d+?,)*?` =>  0 ou mais números seguidos vírgula;
- `\\d+`   => um último número que não é seguido de vírgula.

Exemplo:

```
String t1 = "/aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1";
String t2 = "/aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,23,456,789";
String t3 = "/aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,";
String t4 = "/aluno/1/Teste dos Testes/1,23,456,789,";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/aluno/\\d+?/\\D+?/(\\d+?,)*?\\d+");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(t1).matches());  //true
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(t2).matches());  //true
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(t3).matches());  //false
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(t4).matches());  //false
```

Veja rodando [aqui](https://ideone.com/3PsWa5).